# Broken behavior in Google Test C++, calling wrong constructor

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a constructor that opens a file and throws a std::runtime_error if it fails, the constructor just takes one argument, the filename with path.I'd like to test it like this;

```
TEST(TestTextParser, LoadFileThatDoesntExist) {
    ASSERT_THROW(TextParser(brokenFilePath),std::runtime_error);
}
```

but instead, I have to test it like this as the default, not the single parameter constructor is thrown;

```
TEST(TestTextParser, LoadFileThatDoesntExist) {
try {
        auto c = TextParser(brokenFilePath);
        EXPECT_TRUE(false);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        ASSERT_TRUE(e.what() == ("Unable to open file " + brokenFilePath));
        return;
    }
    EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
```

What's seemingly required is to assign the constructor to something, which forces the use of the proper constructor. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Did you intend to use `ASSERT_THROW` (or possibly `EXPECT_THROW`) instead of `TEST_THROW`?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue Google test. It probably helps to see your class definition. Your original test passes for me: https://godbolt.org/z/dezn5Kzqd

Answer (score 0):

I find the `ASSERT_THROW()` macro bothersome in general (it often does not parse the way I expect). I tend to wrap the test in a lambda then place the lambda in the macro:

```
TEST(TestTextParser, LoadFileThatDoesntExist) {
    auto test = [](){TextParser(brokenFilePath);};
    ASSERT_THROW(test(), std::runtime_error);
}
```

Comment: GTest doesn't have a `TEST_THROW` macro and `{ASSERT|EXPECT}_THROW` rarely needs to resort to lambdas. At least for the basic case like OP has they definitely work as expected.

Comment: Edited original, I used ASSERT_THROW. I can confirm this behavior with both {ASSERT|EXPECT}_THROW. The fundamental problem is that unless you assign the built object, googletest calls the wrong constructor, the parameterless one. You can see this in debug.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for that, seems really unnecessary but a good solution. Bizarre behavior.

Comment: @ixSci Typing quickly last night. Fixed.